# Handle duplicate same column name returned by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax that returned many rows. I'd like to change only the row that has duplicate. This is an example:

This is the rows returned from ajax

```
No    Item     Restock Date    Total
1     Apple     2016-07-09     45000
2     Grape     2016-01-06     17500
3     Grape     2016-07-07     25000
4     Orange    2016-09-09     85000
5     Orange    2016-10-10     77000
6     Orange    2016-11-11     30500
```

This is the rows I expected to be returned from ajax

```
No    Item          Restock Date    Total
    1     Apple     2016-07-09     45000
    2     Grape     2016-01-06     42500 //SUM all Grape
    3     Grape     2016-07-07     
    4     Orange    2016-09-09     
    5     Orange    2016-10-10    192500 //SUM all Orange
    6     Orange    2016-11-11
```

This is my AJAX

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/get_report_beban'); ?>",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType : "json",
                    data: dataSend,
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        var tableData,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6;
                        var no      = 1;

                        $.each(response, function(index, data) {
                            var kd_cbg  = data.KodeOutlet_iBSM;
                            var nm_cbg  = data.NamaOutlet;
                            var total   = parseInt(data.total_pemenuhan);

                            if(nm_cbg == nm_cbg)
                            {
                                alert("duplicate");
                            }

                            t1  = "<tr><td>"+ no++ +"</td>";
                            t2  =     "<td align='center'>"+ fruit_name +"</td>";
                            t3  =     "<td align='left'>"+ date_stock +"</td>";
                            t4  =     "<td align='right'><input type='hidden' class='total_col' value='"+total+"' />"+ total.toLocaleString() +"</td></tr>";

                            tableData += t1+t2+t3+t4;

                            $('#tbl_content').show();
                            $('#tbl_content tbody tr').remove();
                            $('#tbl_content tbody').append(tableData);

                        });

                    }
            });
        });
```

I tried using alert to check duplicate name, but failed. Any help and suggestion are greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be both better and easier to sort that out on the serverside

Comment: can i see your server side code Please .